Excel conditional formatting not applied to all cells as configured in "applies to"
The following (link to a) screenshot shows that I have applied conditional formatting to cells O5 through P8 based on the value in column M (of their corresponding row)...
It can be seen that the formatting is being applied to the cells in column O, but the cells in column P are being ignored. Any suggestions on what is going on here or what I am doing incorrectly?
Condformatconfig


Make those as =$M5=Reviewed

This is what you need to do in Conditional Formatting:


Make Absolute Relative reference --> $M5
• For In Progress:
=$M5="In Progress"


• For Reviewed:
=$M5="Reviewed"


• For Completed:
=$M5="Completed"



Thanks Mayukh. I'd just twigged to the need for "$M" and was just about to answer my own question when I saw your response.

@MarkCalvert sounds good!

@MarkCalvert If Mayukh's answer is correct, then please mark it as such so people will know you question has been answered

@cybernetic.nomad I did try to mark it as correct yesterday but it wouldn't allow me to, done now though.
